# Order when searching for single value in a multi-value field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Example documents:

```
{"id": 1, "categories" : ["A", "C","E"]}
{"id": 2, "categories" : ["A", "C"]}
{"id": 3, "categories" : ["A"]}
{"id": 4, "categories" : ["A"]}
```

When someone searches for a single value "A" in the `categories` field, how can I make sure that document 3 and 4 will always be in higher order than document 1 and 2 since they are closer to the single value "A"?

I have tried this query:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "categories": "A"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but document 3 and 4 are not in top order.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to control the relevance or the `tf/idf` when you are trying to work on cells inside an array. The elasticsearch will treat all the cells and their content like one concatenated string.